# when I create table in mysql8.0 with partition and data directory , the error happened: ERROR 1525 (HY000): Incorrect path value: '/var/lib/mysql/p1'

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE employees1 (

    id INT NOT NULL auto_increment ,

    name varchar(128),

    primary key(id)

) ENGINE=INNODB  

    PARTITION BY LIST(id%10)(

    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (0,1,2,3,4)

    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/var/lib/mysql/p1'

    DATA DIRECTORY = '/var/lib/mysql/p1',

    PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (5,6,7,8,9)

    INDEX DIRECTORY = '/var/lib/mysql/p2'

    DATA DIRECTORY = '/var/lib/mysql/p2'


);
```

what is the  correct path value ?

Comment: Did you create /var/lib/mysql/p1 or are you expecting the create statement to do it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this article: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-directory.html

Basically, you will need to make sure that p1 and p2 exist at the correct location and the OS user trying to access it has the necessary permissions.